# How to "classify" signals?

Tags: data-analysis, signal-processing

I have some signals and I want to classify them into different types. Signals are all sine shape signals, some might have glitches. I know I could classify them base on frequency or amplitude, but is there other ways to classify signals?
Thank you.

Comment: One can encode signals into waves in only 3 ways, amplitude of the wave, frequency of the wave, or phase of the wave (or combinations of them). If phase of the wave is not used in the encoding, for example, it is not necessary to analyze this phase. Ultimately, a signal is good when the original message is decodable, or it is bad when the original message is garbled. There are standard metrics like bits error rate (ber) which compares the number of bits we get right versus the number we get wrong, which can be used to evaluate the system's signal performance.

Comment: It will depend on the context you want to use. For example, you might classify on some characteristic that relates to information you are trying to transmit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A data-driven approach would be to use something like [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to see if your data naturally breaks into distinguishable classes. However that would be more of a question relevant at the [cross-validated stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). The physics version of this question would be something like, how can you understand the processes that produce glitches and how those processes produce the glitch morphology you see.

Comment: @James there are many more ways than only three, just decompose a time function into an arbitrary complete orthogonal set of functions and use the coefficients as information carriers: no phase, no amplitude, no frequency. Those three are the simplest *waveform coding* schemes and historically the first because of the available narrow band passive filters/antennas and modulating/demodulating electronics (AM/FM/PM).

Comment: @hyportnex thank you. Did you mean, from the first part of your comment, we send a 1000 time slice of a non-repeating wave, then take the Fourier transform of the whole wave, giving us  1000 coefficients which is the real data?

Comment: @james Forget Fourier Transforms. Conceptually just take a time signal, a "message" and decompose it into orthogonal functions, or rather take a set of orthogonal functions, say Legendre polynomials, and before summing them you multiply each with a real or complex number, that is modulation. Read Wozencraft-Jacobs Chapter 4, especially 4.3, see https://archive.org/details/principles-of-communication-engineering-wozencraft-jacobs/page/n111/mode/2up Demodulation is the *decomposition* of the noisy received signal into orthogonal waveforms.

Comment: @hyportnex Could i just use 26 levels on the wave amplitude representing alphabets a-z, then encode a single level (representing a letter) every 1 nanosecond or some pre-agreed clock speed?

Comment: @Yes, of course, and that is a special case of the above described orthogonal waveform coding where the basic waveform is one finite length pulse placed repeatedly into non-overlapping slots covering the whole transmission interval, in you question each slot is 1nsec. The information is then buried in the amplitude of each pulse.

Comment: @hyportnex thank you. i gotta look up orthogonal function demodulation.